# String matching where strings contain punctuation

Tags: r, string, string-matching, grepl

I want to find a case insensitive match using `grepl()`.

I have the following list of keywords that I want to find in a **Text** column of my data frame `df`.

```
# There is a long list of words, but for simplification I have provided only a subset.
I, I'm, the, and, to, a, of
```

I want to have the counts of these words separately for each of the data rows. 
I define this word list to be used in the code as:

```
word_list = c('\\bI\\b','\\bthe\\b','\\band\\b','\\bto\\b','\\ba\\b','\\bof\\b')
# Note that I'm is not currently in this word_list
```

In my dataframe `df` I add the columns as below to keep the counts of above words:

```
df$I    = 0
df$IM   = 0   # this is where I need help
df$THE  = 0
df$AND  = 0
df$TO   = 0
df$A    = 0
df$OF   = 0
```

Then I use the following for-loop for each word of the word list to iterate over each row of the required column.

```
# for each word of my word_list
for (i in 1:length(word_list)){ 

  # to search in each row of text response 
  for(j in 1:nrow(df)){

    if(grepl(word_list[i], df$Text[j], ignore.case = T)){   
      df[j,i+4] = (df[j,i+4])    # 4 is added to go to the specific column

    }#if 
  }#for
}#for
```

For a reproducible example dput(df) is as below:

```
dput(df)

structure(list(cluster3 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), userID = c(3016094L, 3042038L, 3079341L, 3079396L, 3130832L, 3130864L, 3148118L, 3148914L, 3149040L, 3150222L), Text = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 8L), .Label = c("I'm alright","I'm stressed", "I am a good person.", "I don't care", "I have a difficult task", "I like it", "I think it doesn't matter", "Let's not argue about this", "Let's see if I can run", "No, I'm not in a mood"), class = "factor"), I = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), IM = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AND = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), THE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), TO = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), OF = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: You can use double quotes `"` to quote a string that has single quotes `'` in it (or vice versa). So just add `"\\bI'm\\b"` to your word list.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor I also just tried that !

Comment: Also, `\\b` is a regular expression pattern so it will be ignored if you set `fixed = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a more streamlined approach:

```
## use a named vector for the word patterns
## with the column names you want to add to `df`
word_list = c('I' = '\\bi\\b', 'THE' = '\\bthe\\b', 'AND' = '\\band\\b',
              'TO' = '\\bto\\b', 'A' = '\\ba\\b', 'OF' = '\\bof\\b', 'IM' = "\\bim")

## use `stringr::str_count` instead of `grepl`
## sapply does the looping and result gathering for us
library(stringr)
results = sapply(word_list, str_count,
   string = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", tolower(df$Text))
)
results
#       I THE AND TO A OF IM
#  [1,] 1   3   2  1 1  1  0
#  [2,] 0   0   1  0 0  0  0
#  [3,] 0   0   0  0 0  0  0
#  [4,] 2   2   3  2 1  1  1
#  [5,] 0   0   0  1 1  0  0
#  [6,] 0   3   2  2 0  0  0
#  [7,] 1   3   0  1 1  0  0
#  [8,] 1   2   0  1 1  1  0
#  [9,] 0   0   0  0 0  0  0
# [10,] 0   0   0  1 2  0  0

## put the results into the data frame based on the names
df[colnames(results)] = data.frame(results)
```

Since we rely on `str_count` which is vectorized, this should be *much* faster than the row-by-row approach.

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. Your solution is easier, however, the counting is incorrect for 'I'. It also includes the counts for "I'm". I have upated the dput(), maybe you can retest your script?

Comment: Ah yes, the apostrophe will be considered a word boundary and match `\\b`. You could try to anticipate all combinations, say use a pattern like `'\\bI[ .,?:;!-()\\[\\]*]'`, but it may be safer to just remove all punctuation in a previous step. Then you can use `'\\bim\\b'` for `I'm` and leave everything else as-is. This is what I would recommend and I'll update the answer to match.

Comment: Could you please further assist me on this? Now, I have a list of positive and negative sentiment words available at: cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html And I want to count how many positive and how many negative words are there per row. This basically means, replacing the word_list from above example with the positive_emotions_list and then with negative_emotion_list. I tried your script on this:
    
POS = sapply(positive_list, str_count, string = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "",tolower(surv_motivate$hyp_massage_exp)))

but it returms zeros on all rows.

Comment: Well, if the word list is in the same format, it should work. Did you make it a named vector, like I did? Is the data structure the same? You really haven't given me any clue as to what is different. Make sure everything looks similar, and if you still have trouble I suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to make my code working by adding the expression in double quotes:

```
word_list = c('\\bI\\b',"\\bI'm\\b",'\\bthe\\b','\\band\\b','\\bto\\b','\\ba\\b','\\bof\\b')
```